# How do you completely disable the Loader in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to completely remove it so it doesn't show, ever. My site isn't using AJAX so it is redundant but still shows.

I've tried this in the `init` event:

```
$.mobile.loader(false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this CSS:

```
.ui-loader {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It still gets appended to the DOM.

Comment: It is still in the DOM but it is not visible. You can't remove it all together even if you disable AJAX. And that little HTML will not bloat your DOM. Other solution would require removing it from that framework itself but that's bad idea on so many levels.

Comment: Are you saying there is no possible setting to stop the DOM injection? That seems a little crazy!

Comment: No, no, no. We are only talking about AJAX loader animation GIF only, I'm not talking about jQuery Mobile and how it handle AJAX page loading. You can't forcefully remove it. But you can hide it. AJAX loaded is connected to AJAX handling but it is NOT bound to it only.

Comment: Yup, I realise that. The AJAX loader is irrelevant in this case but it still injects the html for the loader when the page is set up. I was hoping there was a setting to disable it completely. If that is not the case I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Let me just tell you "Welcome to jQuery Mobile" ;) a horror house. Before jQuery Mobile 1.4 there was a global option to disable loading massage. Basically by setting its text to false you would incidentally disable whole loader. Not it just removed text. New disable option was introduced but it's not working: http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/#option-disabled so currently only viable option for jQM 1.4.X is to disable it through CSS. If you are using older jQuery Mobile version I can show you how it was done before.

Comment: Code like this always makes sense to the author... but not always in production. Thanks!